# Replacing an opening quote when there isn't a closing quote

Tags: javascript, regex

The following code is replacing opening and closing straight double quotes by opening and closing curly double quotes:

```js
const string = `Not dialogue not dialogue.

"Dialogue dialogue.

"Dialogue dialogue."

"Dialogue," not dialogue. "Dialogue."`

const result = string.replace(/"([^"\n\r]*)"/g, '&ldquo;$1&rdquo;')

console.log(result)
```

How to modify this code so the opening straight double quote in `"Dialogue dialogue` (second line) is also replaced by an opening curly double quote (without adding a closing curly double quote at the end of the line)?

Desired output:

```
Not dialogue not dialogue.

&ldquo;Dialogue dialogue.

&ldquo;Dialogue dialogue.&rdquo;

&ldquo;Dialogue,&rdquo; not dialogue. &ldquo;Dialogue.&rdquo;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
const string = `Not dialogue not dialogue.

"Dialogue dialogue.

"Dialogue dialogue."

"Dialogue," not dialogue. "Dialogue."`

const result = string.replace(/"([^"\n\r]*)("|$)/gm, (x,y,z) =>  z == '"' ? `&ldquo;${y}&rdquo;` : `&ldquo;${y}`)

console.log(result)
```

*Details*:

- `"` - a double quote
- `([^"\n\r]*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than `"`, CR and LF
- `("|$)` - Group 2: `"` or end of a line (`m` makes `$` match the end of any line).

The `` (x,y,z) =>  z == '"' ? `&ldquo;${y}&rdquo;` : `&ldquo;${y}` ``  replacement replaces with `&ldquo;` + Group 1 value + `&rdquo;` if Group 2 value is `"`, else, the replacement is `&ldquo;` + Group 1 value.

Comment: Thanks! But, in your output, there's a `&rdquo;` in the second line. I don't want a `&rdquo;` there, since the original output has no quote.

Comment: @alexchenco I updated the solution.